# Cannot remove global picklist after deletion picklist

Tags: picklist, delete, dependent-picklist, global-picklist, undelete

I am trying to delete a global picklist but this references a deleted picklist. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deleted picklist field is still in the system equivalent of a recycle bin (so that you can restore it if needed).  In setup, go to the object where you deleted the picklist, open the custom field list and scroll to the bottom.  There is a hyperlink for `Deleted Fields`.  Click link, then permanently erase the picklist field that you deleted.